# Python Indentation compile error

Tags: python, indentation

I have gotten myself into some python indenting mess. I am not a Python person but had to edit a couple of lines now a big mess. Tried notepad++ the indenting looks perfect to me, but it does not compile - keeps giving **IndentationError: unexpected indent**  I dont know what the expectation is tabs/sapces - the columns are aligned corrctly.

Google/Stackoverflow suggested try using **reindent**. I have python 2.7 (its in the path) it contains reindent (uncompiled). Tried to run the command a few ways, used absolute paths etc, but did not work- **cant find reindent**:

```
>python -m C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\reindent -d C:\Cassandra228\
apache-cassandra\pylib\cqlshlib\copyutil.py

c:\python27\python.exe: No module named C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\reindent
```

How do I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried online beautifiers?

Comment: Could you please post the code.

Comment: It is most likely that you messed up with mixing `spaces` and `tabs`. It would be great if you could provide us the code. Also, I would suggest trying an online formatter like https://pythoniter.appspot.com/ to fix the indentation and then use either `tabs` or `spaces` for indenting.

Answer (score -1):

I currently solved my issue using the special character view in notepad++. There were tabs etc - once I got rid of them the code compiled.